# What is the difference between packages and artifacts?

Tags: terminology, deployment, release-management, release, artifacts

I would like to understand the difference between package and artifact.

Also In what context we should use these terms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mainly an [artifact is the result of of a build phase](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/466/what-is-an-artifact-or-artefact?rq=1), this mean a package is an artifact of a kind.

A package is usually a way to install a software or application, it includes the software itself and some intelligence to setup and configure the software.

Calling an artifact a package usually comes when the artifact (whatever it is, from a .deb to a simple zip file) contain more than just the application, it could be a simple script to help configuring the software and setting proper permissions or other softwares needed.

Answer (score 0):

Also, the term "artifact package" refers to a logical package that can assemble artifacts created in a single build as well as multiple builds.