# Can we consider usage of git lfs for artifacts equally mature strategy to an artifactory?

Tags: artifacts, methodology, artifactory, git-lfs

- Git lfs is just support for large files in Git -> good for example for a video file sample if you need it, right?
- But, if you have large artifacts like a trained model or an uber-jar or some other artifact, what is the benefit to version this binary in git?

Comment: Answer is in the question: versioning... `lfs` is more or less just replacing the actual file in the repo by a text pointer to the real file in a repository, more details [here](https://git-lfs.github.com/)

Comment: Related comment discussion: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/1999/data-science-pipelines-and-monolitic-model-blobs/2001#2001

Answer (score 1):

**What is Git-LFS?**

Git Large File Storage (LFS) prevents that large files need to be stored in git itself.

https://git-lfs.github.com/

> Git Large File Storage (LFS) replaces large files such as audio
>   samples, videos, datasets, and graphics with text pointers inside Git,
>   while storing the file contents on a remote server like GitHub.com or
>   GitHub Enterprise.

**What is artifactory?**

Artifactory stores artifacts, e.g. docker images, jars, wars

**Artifactory vs. Git-lfs**

Artifactory is used to store artifacts while git-lfs is used to prevent that large files are stored in git. If one will store large files in git and one would like to clone this repository it will take a decade before it is cloned.